# 'SPFieldUserValue' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'SPFieldUserValue'

Tags: development, spfielduser

I am trying to remove a user from my `SPFieldUserValueCollection` but I keep get the error

> 'SPFieldUserValue' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'SPFieldUserValue'

Here is my code

```
spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
string variable1 = Page.Request.QueryString["myID"];
int ListItemId = Int32.Parse(variable1);
SPUser userDeleted = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
SPList List = spWeb.Lists["BGAG Learning Calendar"];
SPListItem ListItem = List.GetItemById(ListItemId);
SPFieldUserValueCollection FieldUserValueCollection = (SPFieldUserValueCollection)ListItem["Course Attendies"];
SPFieldUserValueCollection fieldUserValues = new SPFieldUserValueCollection();

foreach (SPFieldUserValue fieldUserValues1 in FieldUserValueCollection)
{
       if (fieldUserValues1.LookupId != userDeleted.ID && fieldUserValues1.LookupValue != userDeleted.Name)
       {
             fieldUserValues1.Add(new SPFieldUserValue(spWeb, fieldUserValues1.LookupId, fieldUserValues1.LookupValue));
       }
}
ListItem["Course Attendies"] = fieldUserValues;
ListItem.Update();
spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are referencing the wrong variable when you try to add your `SPFieldUserValue`.

Look closely at your code.  You create a `SPFieldUserValueCollection` called "fieldUserValues".  You then iterate through another collection, and inside the foreach, the single `SPFieldUserValue` you are working with is called "fieldUserValues1".

Notice that that is nearly identical to the empty collection you created, except it has a "1" on the end.

Now look at the line of code where you are trying to add to the collection.

You are trying to add to "fieldUserValues**1**".  In other words, you are trying to add a new `SPFieldUserValue` into a single `SPFieldUserValue`, **not into a `SPFieldUserValueCollection`**.

You need to change that line of code to be

```
fieldUserValues.Add(new SPFieldUserValue(spWeb, fieldUserValues1.LookupId, fieldUserValues1.LookupValue));
```

Answer (score 4):

Should you not call `Add` on `fieldUserValues` and not `fieldUserValues1` ( that is a `SPFieldUserValue`, not a `SPFieldUserValueCollection`)?

Like

```
foreach (SPFieldUserValue fieldUserValues1 in FieldUserValueCollection)
{
       if (fieldUserValues1.LookupId != userDeleted.ID && fieldUserValues1.LookupValue != userDeleted.Name)
       {
             fieldUserValues.Add(new SPFieldUserValue(spWeb, fieldUserValues1.LookupId, fieldUserValues1.LookupValue));
       }
}
```